# How To Remove Github SSH Key Relics From Past User

Tags: git, github, ssh

I have received a loaner MacBook M1 Air, and have been running into issues trying to use my GitHub SSH key to push to company repositories. I deleted the past keys in the `.ssh` folder, created a new key, and added it to GitHub. I changed the .ssh/config file to reflect my information, and am the only user in the .ssh/known_hosts file. When trying to push a commit, I receive an error that states: `ERROR: Write access to repository not granted. fatal: Could not read from remote repository`.

If I run `ssh -T`, I get a welcome message to the GitHub username of the previous user of this laptop. I can't find any area where this past-user's information is still being stored, having cleared out the .ssh folder and replaced it's contents with my information. When I run `ssh-add -l -E sha256`, the output reflects the past user's account and key.

Inside my .ssh folder, the files are:

- config
- id_ed25519
- id_ed25519.pub
- known_hosts

The information in all these files reflects my GitHub token and account. I am struggling to figure out how to delete all relics of the previous user, or even to find out where they are hiding. Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Since it's a MacBook, and therefore runnning macOS, you'll get the behavior of macOS ssh. That includes *automatically* starting ssh-agent for you and using the macOS keychain to store ssh keys. Check the keychain keys to see if you're providing those. Consider adding `IdentityFile` and `IdentitiesOnly yes` lines to your ssh config, to limit the set of keys you allow ssh to provide to GitHub: you can do this *instead of* removing keys from the OS X keychain, if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

torek nailed it in their comment. I already had `IdentityFile` in my ssh config, pointing to my key. Adding `IdentitiesOnly yes` allowed me to push again, as well as changing the `ssh -T` output to reflect my username. Thank you @torek!